# confusing RVIZ message says triangle count does not match file size

Tags: ros, rviz, stl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We were getting an error message from RVIZ saying that our STL file is too small.
We upgraded from Kinetic to LoggerHead based on so web searching but nothing fixed the issue.
In the end it turned out we needed to ignore that message and look at the next set of messages that told us the resouce could not be located.
All it was was changing file://urdf/urdf.urdf to file:///urdf/urdf.urdf ... we were missing a slash.
Should the triangle count/file size message be displayed when the file is not found? Should the check for the triangle count in the header and the byte count come after the file is found?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275011/confusing-rviz-message-says-triangle-count-does-not-match-file-size/) by [OpenR2](https://answers.ros.org/users/32192/openr2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like an unhelpful error message. You should create an issue on the [tracker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0